# What does the fadeTime for the Citymaps SDK's CEMarker class represent?

Tags: ios, sdk, openstreetmap, citymaps

Documentation claims only this:

```
/** How long it takes the marker to fade in and out when visibility changes. */
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat fadeTime;
```

Does this CGFloat value represent seconds? milliseconds? No matter what value I supply:

```
[marker setFadeTime:3000.0f]; // assume milliseconds
```

or

```
marker.fadeTime = 3.0f;       // assume seconds
```

It doesn't seem to change the behavior.  Any help is appreciated.

(Apologies - not enough reputation points yet to create a `citymaps` tag - any 1500+ members, please feel free to assist!)

Thanks

Comment: Interestingly enough, the developers of CityTags [ask for questions to be tagged on StackOverflow](http://developer.citymaps.com/faq) with [citymaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/citymaps) but the tag didn't exist yet.  As to your question, the CityTags developers should preferably use [NSTimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html), or they need to explain in the .h file what the time represents.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - thanks for that.  This SDK has only recently been released to the public. I'm quite impressed thus far - but, perhaps not surprisingly, as with all things APIs/SDKs, their documentation will need to catch up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer at Citymaps. Thanks for putting up with our, rather bare, documentation.
Looking at the docs made me realize that we're missing a few key properties on markers, both on iOS and android (oops).

To answer your question, fadeTime will adjust the speed that the marker fades in or out by when its visibility changes. Right now, visibility will only be changed through the collision detection feature of CEMarkerGroup. One of those missing properties I mentioned was a 'hidden' property for iOS, or a 'visibility' property on Android, similar to their respective View class.

I've updated our docs a bit to answer the question of what unit this value is. We try to follow the convention of the platform. For iOS, this value is in seconds. On Android, this value is in milliseconds.

Comment: thanks.  I got the gist of what the property is, but what I meant was: what does the CGFloat `value` represent? (is it seconds? milliseconds?, etc.)  So, if I use `[marker setFadeTime:3000.0f];` am I requisition 3000 milliseconds or 3000 seconds?  Sorry the confusion.

Comment: Much appreciated! Love this SDK so far.